# Как записывать в журнал посещения страницы?

Tags: веб-программирование

Необходимо создать страничку в интернете, где будет отмечаться mac-адрес посетителей, время посещения, время ухода... Всё это должно быть записано в журнал. Как это сделать? Какой язык программирования? Есть ли стандартные функции? Можно ли где-то скачать что-то подобное?

Answer (score 1):

Надо смотреть в сторону $_SERVER, если используется PHP для написания странички.
MAC-адрес вы сможете узнать только у тех, кто находится с вами в одной подсети. Если же сайт будет находиться в интернете, вы никогда не узнаете МАС ваших посетителей.

Comment: Поправка: если вы используете специфический javascript, то получить mac возможно, естественно это смогут отключить пользователи.

Comment: Поправка: вы ошибаетесь. ActiveX != JavaScript.